what is the difference between "ship", "deliver" and "send", e.g. "we will ship/deliver/send the item to your house"?
According to my study, it seems "to ship" means to take an item to a carrier who will "deliver" it to your house.

If a shop said "we will ship the item to you/ your house", would that be wrong because "ship" is to move the item to a carrier not to your house?
Does "we will deliver the item to your house" sound better?
But the shop doesn't have an employee who does the delivering.
Is it better to say "we will have the item delivered to you (by a carrier)"?
But the shop has an employee who will take the item to a carrier.
Is it necessary to say "we will ship the item and have it delivered to your house by next Monday"?
What about "send"? I feel like "send" is better used for letters or parcels.

You need to show us your "study" and not ask questions without making an effort at research, which you then share with us.

To "ship a package to someone" means "to make arrangements with a carrier to transport the item from the shipper's location to someone's location." The precise nature of the arrangements are not entailed. It could be a daily pickup at the shipper's location or the shipper could be responsible for bringing the package to the carrier. The carrier could be a "common carrier" or the postal service.
to deliver a package to someone means to bring it to them. To have it delivered means to arrange to have it brought to them.   (But you might find some people saying "deliver it" when what they intend to do is have it delivered.)
To mail a package means to send it via the postal service, though that distinction is becoming blurred as the postal services and the common carriers are cooperating more and more.
To send a package is vague and non-committal with respect to the carrier and could mean "ship" or "mail".  It is also not specific with respect to the item's size (letter, parcel, big box, etc). The verb "send" is the least specific of the four verbs here, and it would typically be used in imprecise conversation, not in formal transactional language agreed to by buyer and seller, say.

The three verbs send, ship and deliver all describe the same activity from different perspectives, in the same way as "depart" and "arrive".
Send and ship can be used in relation to the point of departure:

Can you please send these documents [from our office] today?
We can't ship anything [from our country] today, because it's a public holiday

Deliver can be used in relation to the point of arrival:

We will deliver your order [to you] this morning

All three can also used to describe the entire end-to-end process. Generally, none of them implicitly identifies who will transport an actual item, so "we will deliver... " does not necessarily mean that one of our own staff will turn up on your doorstep.

My Shopee page has just these two: 'To Ship' and 'To Receive' without further breakdown into the different legs.  There’re also no mentions on the types of vehicles.  So it’s fine to say

we will send (or deliver) the item to your house

without having to differentiate the legs or the types of vehicles.
Though ship is possible, it’s not my preference if the journey doesn't involve another country.
Collins Dictionary's sense 7 defines ship:

to place, transport, or travel on any conveyance, esp aboard a ship


ship the microscopes by aeroplane

The three verbs mean the same in this context, with send the most common followed by deliver and ship for VERB a parcel.
For VERB an item, send was again more common than the other two for many decades until the later part of the last century when the usage pattern started to get erratic.
